How to calculate average number of outgoing edges per user in a single gremlin query?
I am struggling to calculate average number of outgoing edges per user. I've tried
g.V().hasLabel('user').as('users').
    outE('IS_FRIENDS_WITH').
    project('usersC','edgesC').
        by(__.select('users').count()).
        by(__.count()).next()

which just returns a list of maps of {'userC': 1, 'edgesC': 1}, which in retrospect makes sense.
I tried a few other things, running into issues like how count or project effectively collapse / end a traversal, sideEffect not doing what I hoped, etc.

The key was the aggregate step:
await gr.V().hasLabel('user').aggregate('usersCount').
    outE('IS_FRIENDS_WITH').aggregate('edgesCount').
    project('usersC','edgesC').
        by(__.select('usersCount').count(gremlin.process.scope.local)).
        by(__.select('edgesCount').count(gremlin.process.scope.local)).
        math('edgesC / usersC').next();

